# Duplication code - error correction

Tags: coding-theory

Explain how the duplication code given by {00,11,22} with letters in the set $\mathbb{Z}$/3 can detect one error.

If I were to construct a table of Hamming distances, I would show that the minimal distance is 2, and thus the error detection is 1 because C is n error detecting iff the minimal distance is $\geq$ n+1

Is this correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: That is correct. But the argument *If a single error happened, then the components of the received vector are distinct. Hence that is not a codeword and an error has occured* may be conceptually easier. Your call :-)

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered in the comments by [Snowball](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/24875/snowball) and [Jyrki Lahtonen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen), both stating that the argument in the post is correct. Additionally, Jyrki Lahtonen offered a more intuitive way of interpreting the solution.

From the comments:

"That is correct. But the argument *If a single error happened, then the components of the received vector are distinct. Hence that is not a codeword and an error has occured* may be conceptually easier. Your call :-)"